# Scatter plot from DataFrame with double header

Tags: python, pandas

Having a DataFrame structured as follows:

```
                 A            B
country       C     D     C      D
Albany      2.05    4    1.85    4
China       2.67    3    1.21    3
Portugal    1.44    6    2.34    6
France      5.83    3    2.50    3
Greece      0.63    6    3.02    6
```

I don't know how can I make a scatter plot where, choosing A or B, gives me a scatter with x=C and y=D for every country. If I do it like this it gives me a KeyError:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='C', y='D')
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can `group` over the 0th level of the columns to plot each separately. Grouping only splits the DataFrame, it doesn't modify anything so you can either use tuples as the keys or use `DataFrame.xs` to remove the now redundant MultiIndex level.

```
for idx, gp in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
    gp.xs(idx, level=0, axis=1).plot.scatter(x='C', y='D', title=idx)
```

[image]
[image]

---

Or if you want one plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cd = {'A': 'red', 'B':'blue'}  # color by group

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for idx, gp in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1):
    gp.xs(idx, level=0, axis=1).plot.scatter(x='C', y='D', ax=ax, label=idx, c=cd[idx])
```

[image]